# How to annotate a diff in bitbucket to see commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a feature branch. I am looking at the diff of the feature branch compared to master. i want to be able to annotate this view to see the commit details for each line of code.

--

I am looking to do this in either bitbucket or a third party tool.

Comment: Doesn't gitk do this? `gitk master..feature`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a look at difflame, a tool I created to do precisely that. Let me know how it goes.

https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

It's not bullet-proof, just in case.

Comment: Did it provide you with the info you needed?